# Multiple edits accepted?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I recently attempted to edit [this ansewer](https://superuser.com/questions/396313/excel-2010-takes-forever-to-open/565964#565964) made by [user207162](https://superuser.com/users/207162/user207162). To my annoyance I found I could not. I was reviewing him because it was his first post and was almost forced to click no action needed due to the fact that I could not edit. Why aren't multiple edit suggestions allowed. When doing this the person reviewing the edits can simply choose the one that is best. We shouldn't deny edits on questions that need them.

This is what I attempted to edit to to say.

I found a method that seemed to work for me. Please not I am currently using IE8 and Excel 2010 on a 64-bit Windows 7 computer.

1. Start Internet Explorer 8
2. Go to "Tools" menu
3. Go to "Internet Options"
4. Go to "Security" tab
5. Go to "Local Intranet"
6. Click on "Sites" button
7. Un-check "Automatically detect intranet network"

Now your Excel spreadsheet should open instantly.

Comment: You can always *Skip* a review, you shouldn't be forced to click "No action needed".

Comment: True, skipping doesn't solve to problem however.

Comment: Just for clarification, you were reviewing a question and wanted to edit it, but that wasn't possible because there was already a pending edit. Correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat of an unfortunate circumstance. You can't approve already existing suggested edits, yet, you've been shown a post that had a suggested edit pending.

In general, this is intended behavior. You're not supposed to be able to make another edit while a previous edit is still under review.

- [Missing edit link?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84671/missing-edit-link)
- [Cannot Edit Certain Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114211/cannot-edit-certain-question)

In practice, this shouldn't happen too often. If it happens, you should just *skip* the review and review another post.

If you feel like this is not an acceptable solution and that you shouldn't be seeing any posts that you can't edit in the review queue, please tag your question [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) and maybe adjust the body of your question to more directly address this specific issue.

Comment: That's not the only problem. My problem is that we should have multiple edits. I don't understand why we can't make edits while other edits are under review.

Comment: @Griffin: If your edit would be based on the first edit, but then the first edit is rejected, how would the system handle your edit now? If all edits would be based on the same source post, then one would replace the other.

Comment: @Griffin The core reason for limiting to one pending edit is that the edit is not visible to anyone but the editor and reviewers until it is approved.  The system needs some way to handle concurrent edits from low-rep users and limiting it to one at a time is the method the developers chose.  The idea of our edit system is to allow for sequential edits iteratively improving a post - the sequence is broken if we allow multiple pending edits simultaneously.

Comment: So why can't the reviewer be presented with multiple options?

Comment: @Griffin What additional open would you like?  If you can't edit it, you can still comment, vote, flag, or close assuming you have privs for those actions.

Comment: None of those allow me to edit however. I would like to be able to submit an edit when another edit has already been submitted.

Comment: @Griffin: You *can* edit (by reviewing the existing edit and then writing your own), just not with the amount of reputation you currently have. You're of course free to request this feature, but I wouldn't get my hopes up :)

Comment: @OliverSalzburg I know. I just think anyone should be able to do it.

Comment: Not review but be able to add an edit at any time